# Giving $8$ identical candy bars to given out to $4$ people

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Problem:

Suppose that there are $8$ identical candy bars to given out to $4$ people with no
restrictions. How many different ways can the candy bars be given out?

Answer:

I want to apply the following fact:
The number of ways to select $n$ objects from a set of $m$ items is
$$ { {n+m-1} \choose {m-1} } $$
if there is no limitation on the number of each item available and
objects of the same item are indistinguishable.

In this case, we have $n = 8$ and $m = 4$. Let $c$ be the count we are looking for.
\begin{align*}
c &= { {8+4-1} \choose {4-1} } = { {11} \choose {3} } \\
c &= \dfrac{ 11(10)(9) }{ 3(2)} = 11(5)(3) \\
c &= 165
\end{align*}
Is my solution right?

Comment: Yes, assuming that a person can receive zero and that be okay.  If you insist on each person receiving at least one then you can think of it as first giving one to each and then distributing the remaining around allowing zeroes of the extra.

Comment: @JMoravitz If you could post your comment as an answer, I could accept the answer and close the question.